# Post variables not set when EnableEventValidation set to 'false'

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation, events, post

So I have a jQuery dialog box within an ASP.NET WebForm application from which I post the content of all the contained controls to another page. The problem is the FileUpload control. When EnablEventValidation is set to true, which I suppose it is by default, I get this error...

```
Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using <pages enableEventValidation="true"/> in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.
```

...and if I set `EnableEventValidation='false'`, the image set in the `FileUpload` control is posted, but all my other posted values come back as null. So I *think* I either need to disable `EventValidation` for *just* the `FileUpload` control, or validate it manually somehow. But I'm not sure how to do either. And I don't know why all my other post values should come up null if `EnableEventValidation` is set to false. Here's my dialog markup...

```
 <div class="divDialog" style="display: none">
            <table style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox></td>
                    <td>Last Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        How Old are You?
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAge" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        How Many Siblings do You Have?
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNumberSiblings" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        What is your birthday?
                        <input type="text" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Please Choose a Picture to Upload:
                        <asp:FileUpload ID="fupUserPicture" runat="server" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClientClick="forcebtnHiddenClick(); return false;" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
```

EDIT: Also, this may relevant, the dialog div is appended to a div which is inside the form after it's created. Here's the form and div markup...

```
<form id="frmDialog" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="btnDisplayDialog" runat="server" Text="Click to Display Login Dialog" OnClientClick="showDialog(); return false;" />
        <div class="divInnerForm"></div>
```

...

```
</div>
<asp:Button ID="btnHidden" runat="server" Text="" Visible="false" ClientIDMode="Predictable"  OnClick="btnHidden_Click"/>
```

..and here's the jQuery script...

```
function showDialog() {
    $('.divDialog').dialog({
        modal: true, show: 'slide', width: 500,
        open: function (event, ui) {
            $('.divInnerForm').append($(this).parent());
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Is your dialog inside an update panel?

Comment: No, it's inside a div which is inside the form, but it has to be appended to this div with a jQuery script after it's created. I'll post that code/markup now...

Comment: And only for awareness, did you try to remove that "dinamic" behaviour and watch the component response?

Comment: If I remove the script jQuery moves the dialog box outside of the form (which it is initially inside in the markup), so there's no way to post without the showDialog() script.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be nested form tags. Since you are using asp.net webform, i assume you have a

```
 <form runat="server">
```

tag enclosing the body of the page. And since the plugin creates a form tag around a div, you may have nested form tags i.e. a form tag inside of another form tag. And since nested forms are not html complaint, the browsers behave weirdly processing those.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No, I didn't add another form, I just added a class attribute to the default form ASP Webforms provides. So there are no nested forms or anything, I checked the source page.